# How to make this nodejs api Fast for CPU Intensive task

Tags: javascript, api, optimization, cpu

I am trying to show Nodejs is not good for CPU Intensive tasks.
In this code, I created the async function `mySlowFunction` that accepts baseNumber.
When I hit `http://localhost:8080` with query params 12 it takes 5 sec.
What If 5 subsequent request is being made to this api for query params 11,89,23,12,23? It would be very slow.
In this kind of scenario is it really good to use NodeJs?[i.e for CPU Intensive Task]. If yes, then how can I make this fast?

```
async function mySlowFunction(baseNumber) {
  let result = 0; 
  for (var i = Math.pow(baseNumber, 7); i >= 0; i--) {    
    result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
  };
  return result;
}
const express = require('express');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
const csrf = require('csurf');
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieparser());
app.get("/",async(req,res)=>{
    let data = await mySlowFunction(req.query.base);
    res.json({data})
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: If the code you are doing is blocking, use https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html.  Ps, the async on you slow function will do nothing..

Answer (score 1):

I have a very general answer.

1. You can precalculate the results if query params are limited.
   You can store results in files or database query them.
2. You can cache results.
   If there is no result for query param in db, calculate it and save it to db.